# Excel, find specific date in a cell

Tags: excel

I started learning Excel. I have this sheet with a lot of dates and information regarding each of the date. The date ranges from 2017, to 2020. I want to extract the information, for a specific year, for example 2017.

For example,
31/12/2017 in Cell B2
4 in Cell D2

I have tried doing
`IF(FIND(2017,B2),"D2", "")`
But it gives me #VALUE! .(Expected output is 4)

I am thinking maybe it is because of the date format?

Comment: This question should be updated with a data example. Please, post your input and expected output. It sounds like you may benefit from VLOOKUP or SUMIF

Comment: I have updated the question, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may use VLOOKUP

> [VLOOKUP
> Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

As example:

[image]

My formula in cell G2 is:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2;$B$3:$D$23;3;FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you, would it be possible to extract information from all the cells, that has '2017' in the date? Not the exact date?

Comment: That's a totally different question, and you should open a new one. But not sure if with normal formulas you could extract all values. Maybe with function FILTER (only Excel 365)

Answer (score 0):

Say we start with:

[image]

and we want the 2017 items.  Running the short VBA macro:

```
Sub Framm()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1:B21")

    r.AutoFilter
    r.AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & DateSerial(2017, 1, 1), _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<=" & DateSerial(2017, 12, 31)
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]